# Rename a selected row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I rename the value? It's giving me the last selected value in IN() clause.

```
SELECT cf_1573, SUM(counter) AS lyncs 
FROM (
 SELECT 
  cf_1573,
  COUNT(cf_1573) AS counter 
 FROM vtiger_purchaseordercf 
 WHERE cf_1573
 IN('Lync Front End (Std)','Lync Front End (Ent)','Lync Backend',
    'Lync Edge','Lync SBA','Lync DNS Checks','Lync Certificate Checks')
 GROUP BY cf_1573
) AS mslync
```

I have this output:

```
cf_1573                 |lyncs
Lync Certificate Checks | 8
```

The `sub-query` gave me this:

```
cf_1573                 | counter
Lync Certificate Checks | 1
Lync DNS Check          | 3
Lync Edge               | 1
Lync SBA                | 3
```

I want the output to display "Data Lync" instead of "Lync Certificate Checks" which is the last value in my `IN() clause`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Below Query.

```
SELECT 'Data Lync' as `cf_1573`, SUM(counter) AS lyncs 
FROM (
 SELECT 
  cf_1573,
  COUNT(cf_1573) AS counter 
 FROM vtiger_purchaseordercf 
 WHERE cf_1573
 IN('Lync Front End (Std)','Lync Front End (Ent)','Lync Backend',
    'Lync Edge','Lync SBA','Lync DNS Checks','Lync Certificate Checks')
 GROUP BY cf_1573
) AS mslync
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply CASE WHEN to it

```
SELECT 
cf_1573  = CASE 
           WHEN cf_1573 = 'Lync Certificate Checks' THEN 'Data Lync' 
           ELSE cf_1573 
          END  , 
SUM(counter) AS lyncs 
FROM
(  SELECT 
   cf_1573, 
   COUNT(cf_1573) AS counter
   FROM vtiger_purchaseordercf 
   WHERE cf_1573  IN ('Lync Front End (Std)','Lync Front End (Ent)',
                      'Lync Backend','Lync Edge','Lync SBA','Lync DNS Checks',
                      'Lync Certificate Checks')GROUP BY cf_1573) AS mslync
                     )
)table_A
```

Comment: it's giving me 0 as the new field value